# what is the apigee target default timeout , I am seeing 404 after 10 secs

Tags: apigee

what is the APIGee target URL default timeout ?
 I am seeing 404 after 10 secs on my services and what is the way to change default time outs

Answer (score 2):

404s generally indicate that your URL is incorrect -- this means that the resource was not found, not that the backend timed out.

The target timeouts can be modified using TargetEndpoint/HTTPTargetConnection, as shown in the following image:

[image: TargetEndpoint/HTTPTargetConnection]

The arrow shows where you click to see the entire TargetEndpoint configuration. Update the properties as shown for the connect and I/O timeouts (number of milliseconds). The defaults are shown (connect default is 1 minute and I/O defaults to 2 minutes).

Check out the [Apigee docs on Endpoint Configuration](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/endpoint-properties-reference) for more info.

Comment: Although you can change the target timeout in the Properties, Apigee is downstream from load balancers with a 60 second timeout so keep that in mind if you tinker with timeouts.  The Load Balancer might time out while Apigee is still waiting if you set the Apigee timeout too long which would keep you from being able to manage the proper error messages.

Comment: True. If you are a paid customer, and you need a longer timeout, you can contact Apigee support to discuss extending your load balancer timeout.